# How to resize picture taken from iPhone Camera to lower resolution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to resize picture taken from iPhone Camera to lower resolution?
I want to take picture from iPhone camera and save it to lower resolution in my application. ( for saving the space)
Or Is it possible to display option of picture size like on sending email of picture?

Comment: what the mean of picture size...mean after inserting in mail ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compress your image using `compressionQuality` value,

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    //Imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(<#UIImage *image#>, <#CGFloat compressionQuality#>);

    Imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],0);
}
```

And you can set size with name

```
    NSLog(@"Video size >> %d",(videodta.length/1024)/1024);
    [picker addAttachmentData:videodta mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Data (size = %d MB)",(videodta.length/1024)/1024 ]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)imageToCompress scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [imageToCompress drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to display option of picture size like on sending email of picture from iPhone?